# Find the Vectorial Equation of the intersection between surfaces $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $g(x,y) = xy + 10$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

I'm not really sure how to do this, I guessed it had something to do with Vector Functions but overall couldn't find a way to do it. Can you please help?

The equations are:

$$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2
\ g(x,y) = xy + 10 $$

and I need a Vectorial equation.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot guess what "the curve between those surfaces" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Perhaps the intersection of loci in $\Bbb R^3$ $$\left\{(x,y,f(x,y))\,:\,x,y\in\Bbb R\right\}\cap \left\{(x,y,g(x,y))\,:\,x,y\in\Bbb R\right\}\quad ?$$

Comment: Sorry, it's the intersection between the surfaces. I guess it doesn't have anything to do with loci

Comment: @LunaDebb If you are interested in a solution in Cartesian coordinates, be my guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look for the intersection of the two surfaces (which are a paraboloid and a hyperbolic paraboloid):

$$\tag{0}\cases{z=x^2+y^2 &  (a)\\z=xy+10 &  (b)}$$

Let $(r,\theta)$ be the polar coordinates of $(x,y)$; i.e,

$$\tag{1}x=r \cos(\theta), \ \ y=r \sin(\theta).$$

Plugging these expressions in (0)(a) gives

$$\tag{2}r=\sqrt{z}.$$

Using $(0)(b)$, $(1)$  and $(2)$: $z=\sqrt{z} \cos(\theta) \sqrt{z}\sin(\theta)+10$, yielding:

$$z(1-\frac12 \sin(2 \theta))=10 \ \ \iff z=f(\theta) \ \ \text{with} \ \ f(\theta):=\dfrac{20}{2-\sin(2 \theta)}$$

Plugging this expression of $z$ in $(1)$ gives the final description of the intersection curve as a vector function of one variable, the polar angle:

$$\cases{x=\sqrt{f(\theta)}\cos(\theta)\\y=\sqrt{f(\theta)}\sin(\theta)\\z=f(\theta)}$$

(valid for any value of $\theta$ because $f(\theta)>0$ )

Comment: So, overall for my answer I would have to plug the value of  f(θ) into the parametrization values?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: So, r(θ) = sqrt(202−sin(2θ))cos(θ) i +sqrt(202−sin(2θ))cos(θ) j +202−sin(2θ) k ?

Comment: Yes. But with a "divide" sign between the $20$s and the $2$s.

Comment: And just before $\vec{j}$, it is $\sin(\theta)$, not $\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a paraboloid (red colour), $g$ is a hyperbolic paraboloid (green colour):

[image]
[image]
(Large versions: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAc4m.png) and [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0c8R.png))

The intersection reminds me of a Lissajous curve.

For the intersection points we have
$$
x^2 + y^2 = xy + 10 \iff \\
0 = x^2 + y^2 - xy - 10
$$
This seems to be a cylinder with elliptic cross section.
$$
x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\xi + \eta) \\
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\xi - \eta)
$$
So we get
\begin{align}
0 &= x^2 + y^2 - xy - 10 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\xi^2 + \eta^2 + 2\xi\eta)
+ \frac{1}{2}(\xi^2 + \eta^2 - 2\xi\eta)
- \frac{1}{2}(\xi^2 - \eta^2) - 10 \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 + \frac{3}{2} \eta^2 - 10 \iff \\
\end{align}
$$
\left( \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{20}} \right)^2 +
\left( \frac{\eta}{\sqrt{20/3}} \right)^2 = 1
$$
We can parameterize
$$
\xi(t) = \sqrt{20} \cos(2\pi t) \\
\eta(t) = \sqrt{20/3} \sin(2\pi t)
$$
for $t \in [0, 2\pi)$ and thus with $z = x^2 + y^2 = \xi^2 + \eta^2$ get
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \sqrt{10} \cos(2\pi t) + \sqrt{10/3} \sin(2\pi t) \\
y(t) &= \sqrt{10} \cos(2\pi t) - \sqrt{10/3} \sin(2\pi t) \\
z(t) &= 20 \cos(2\pi t)^2 + (20/3) \sin(2\pi t)^2 \\
     &= (40/3) \cos(2\pi t)^2 + (20/3)
\end{align}
The left image shows the ellipse in $\xi$-$\eta$-coordinates (light green), in $x$-$y$-coordinates (pink) and the scene in $3D$ (right image).

[image]
[image]

(Large versions: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clq7x.png) and [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlFbN.png))

You can fiddle with an interactive version [here](https://ggbm.at/GHVhsv7D):

- adjust the $t$ slider in the left window and see the points on the ellipses ($A(t)$, $B(t)$) and the intersection curve ($C(t)$) change.
- drag the upper part of the right 3D view to change the 3D view