# What's the volume of the intersection between f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2 and g(x,y) = xy+10?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, recreational-mathematics, surface-integrals

I tried to do it using just normal coordinates but I didn't get anywhere. How would you do it?

This is the continuation of the question in: 
math.stackexchange.com/q/2021557

Comment: Give the reference to your previous question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2021557)

Comment: Edited successfully :)