# How can I optimize f(x,y) bound to g(x,y) = 11?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

How can I optimize this? I think it was solved using lagrange multipliers but don't know how to continue!

f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
g(x,y)=xy+10

In the final part of
[Find the Vectorial Equation of the intersection between surfaces $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $g(x,y) = xy + 10$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021557/find-the-vectorial-equation-of-the-intersection-between-surfaces-fx-y-x2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Lagrande multipliers: $$g(x,y)=11\iff xy=1\iff x=\frac1y.$$
Now plug this into $f$. You will obtain a function in a single variable, which you can then mimize using the classical method of taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero.